# PHP code errors. Need to make use of arrays and for loops

Tags: php, html

I can tell that I'm making a really silly mistake here. Can someone please help me out by correcting my code? Probably an issue with my loop.

```
<?php

        $students = array("Sauer Jeppe", "Von Weilligh", "Troy Commisioner", "Paul Krugger", "Jacob Maree");
        $grades = array(75, 44, 60, 62, 70);

        for($i=0; $i<count($students); $i++){

            for($j=0; $j<count($grades); $j++){


                if($grades[$j] >= 70){

                    echo"$students[$i] scored a Distinction.";
                }

                elseif($grades[$j] >= 50){

                    echo"$students[$i] scored a Pass.";
                }

                elseif($grades[$j] >= 0){

                    echo"$students[$i] scored a Fail.";
                }

            }

        }

    ?>
```

It's meant to display:

**Sauer Jeppe scored a Distinction.**

**Von Weilligh scored a Fail.**

**Troy Commisioner scored a Pass.**

**Paul Krugger scored a Pass.**

**Jacob Maree scored a Distinction.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for inner `for` loop, just take the value from `$grades` under the same key `$i`:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($students); $i++){
    $grade = $grades[$i];
    if($grade >= 70){
        echo"$students[$i] scored a Distinction.";
    } elseif ($grade >= 50){
        echo"$students[$i] scored a Pass.";
    } elseif ($grade >= 0){
        echo"$students[$i] scored a Fail.";
    }
}
```